# sms api using php not working even it is error free

Tags: php, api, curl, sms, remote-server

I am trying to send SMS using an API
its working fine in my local
but it is not working in remote server and it s not giving any error also.
if any 1 knows the reason for this then please tell me the solution

following code i am using

`function execute($url)
    {

```
    $ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $output=curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    return $output;

}   `
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check the [46elks](http://www.46elks.com) git repo with [examples](https://github.com/46elks/samples) of how to make requests without CURL in PHP to send SMS, as well as some other examples for receiving SMS and make and receive phone calls.

Answer (score 0):

You need libcurl library installed on that machine in order to use php-curl extension. Also look in php.ini if you have extension=php_curl.so uncommented. Try to add this code to make sure everything is fine:

```
    if(function_exists('curl_exec')) {
       echo 'curl is running';
    } else {
       echo 'curl is not running';
    }
```

Also, don't you have any post fields for the request ? You can do that with CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS. Documentation is [here](https://www.php.net/curl)

Comment: if i call $response = file_get_contents($url);  sms is going, does it will give any problem if send like this?

Comment: well, the only difference between file_get_contents and your curl example is that the curl example is doing post, did you try to remove the post in the curl example ?

Comment: yes it is working without post,but is it correct way?

Comment: APIs documentation should clearly state what kind of request that command needs.

Comment: they r saying that it is post only but for us it is not working with that